# Javascript Grouping CheckBoxes - Should act as RadioButton between the groups

Tags: angularjs

The following form has got 3 radio buttons and 5 check boxes in an array. Radio1 shows CB1 , Radio2 shows CB2,CB3 and CB4, and finally Radio3 shows CB5. I want to uncheck the checkbox when i select a checkbox from another group. That is if CB1 is selected first and if i click any of the other check boxes from the other 2 groups, CB1 should be unchecked. I did like below, but it not working properly.

HTML

```
    <form>
        <label class="radio-inline" >
        <input value="1" type="radio" ng-model="radioM" >Main1</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input value="2" type="radio" ng-model="radioM" >Main2</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input value="3" type="radio" ng-model="radioM" >Main3</label>
        <div class="">
        <label ng-repeat="branch in branches" >
        <input  type="checkbox" name="selectedBranches[]" value="{{branch.value}}" 
                ng-model="branch.selected" ng-click="unChecker()"  >{{branch.name}}
        </label></div> 
        </form>
```

Controller

```
$scope.branches= [ { name: 'B1', selected: false, value: '1'},
                   { name: 'B2', selected: false, value: '2'},
                   { name: 'B3', selected: false, value: '3'},
                   { name: 'B4', selected: false, value: '4'}
                   { name: 'B5', selected: false, value: '5'}
                  ];
$scope.unChecker = function () {
         if( $scope.branches[0].selected==true) {
         $scope.branches[1].selected=false;
         $scope.branches[2].selected=false;
         $scope.branches[3].selected=false;
         $scope.branches[4].selected=false;
          }
         if $scope.branches[1].selected==true || $scope.branches[2].selected ==true
                        || $scope.branches[3].selected==true){
         $scope.branches[0].selected=false;
         $scope.branches[4].selected=false;
       }
         if( $scope.branches[4].selected==true) {
          $scope.branches[0].selected=false;
          $scope.branches[1].selected=false;
          $scope.branches[2].selected=false;
          $scope.branches[3].selected=false;
         }
};
```

Comment: I don't understand. What's the use of the radios then? They don't seem to do anything here. They're not even mutually exclusive like radio buttons should be.

Comment: I get value from radio and checkbox to run query

Comment: So, the sentence "Radio1 shows CB1 , Radio2 shows CB2,CB3 and CB4, and finally Radio3 shows CB5" in your question is false, right? They don't show or hide anything. Why do you use radio buttons and not making them mutually exclusive as they should be? And why do they all share the same ngModel. I'm asking because neither the explanation nor the code make much sense, and they don't match with each other.

Comment: Actually i show and hide checkboxes. If i click radio1 it shows cb1 etc

Comment: Then why don't you show that in the posted code, and why don't you just uncheck the hidden checkboxes when hiding them?

Comment: Sorry i thought it was not need. Will change it in the future. Your second question is my question. To do that i did like this. But not able to project as question in right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the code as you expect.

Note: I haven't done anything with the radio buttons as you didn't ask anything.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('CheckBoxController', function($scope) {
  $scope.branches = [ 
   { name: 'B1', selected: false, value: '1', group: 'A'},
                   { name: 'B2', selected: false, value: '2', group: 'B'},
                   { name: 'B3', selected: false, value: '3', group: 'B'},
                   { name: 'B4', selected: false, value: '4', group: 'B'},
                   { name: 'B5', selected: false, value: '5', group: 'C'}
                  ];
  
$scope.unChecker = function (index) {
   var group = $scope.branches[index].group;
   angular.forEach($scope.branches, function(obj, i){
     if(obj.group !== group) {
       obj.selected = false;
     }
   });
}; 

});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-controller="CheckBoxController">
        <label class="radio-inline" >
        <input value="1" type="radio" ng-model="radioM" >Main1</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input value="2" type="radio" ng-model="radioM" >Main2</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input value="3" type="radio" ng-model="radioM" >Main3</label>
        <div class="">
        <label ng-repeat="branch in branches" >
        <input  type="checkbox" name="selectedBranches{{$index}}" value="{{branch.value}}" 
                ng-model="branch.selected" ng-change="unChecker($index)"  >{{branch.name}}
        </label></div> 
        </form>
```

Comment: If i select B2 and then B3 it should not uncheck. That is with in a group i should be able to select multiple checkboxes. here B1 , B2/B3/B4 and B5 are 3 groups.

Comment: How do check they are same group? Any property to check from the json?

Comment: Actually i show and hide checkboxes. If i click radio1 it shows cb1 etc

Comment: Okay, I have created a property `group` in the `json` and handled it. Please check.

Comment: Okay will Check now

Comment: Thanks it works as i wanted. i have accepted your answer and upvoted.

Comment: @user3844782 Great :-)